# REST service how to pass JSON for parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf-rest

I have created a WCF REST API:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/checkEmail")]
RestResponse<bool> checkEmail(string EmailId);
```

JSON request is:

```
{ "EmailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com" }
```

It is working as expected. But after some code review changes I changed the param in method to

```
checkEmail(string emailId);
```

i.e. changed it in to camel case. How can I modify my code to use same JSON request i.e. API call should remain same

```
{ "EmailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com" }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do that, without breaking your `OperationContract`, but I'm curious at what others would say.

Comment: yes Frank, i thought so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you. It works in a limited test I did. I created a class which has two properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmailParms
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling=DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
    public virtual string EmailId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling=DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
    public virtual string emailId { get; set; }
}
```

The `JsonPropertyAttribute` is part of [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/).

And then you change your `checkEmail` to have:

```
RestResponse<bool> checkEmail(Emailparms emailParms);
```

The `IgnoreAndPopulate` basically deserializes a property that is missing from that json data, and gives it the property's default value.

Now, in your method, you just have to check the values of `emailId` and `EmailId` in `emailParms` and decide which to use.

In my test, it worked for any of these:

```
{ "EmailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com" }
{ "emailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com" }
{ "EmailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com", "emailId" :"youremail@yahoo.com" }
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. It worked. Moreover, you explain things very clearly. I learnt few things in such a small but informative paragraph